# Помогите с проблемой, отловить нажатие кнопки в боте на telegram в golang

Tags: telegram-bot, golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api"
)

var numericKeyboard = tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardMarkup(
    tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardRow(
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY1", "KEY1"),
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY2", "KEY2"),
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY3", "KEY3"),
    ),
)

var numericKeyboard2 = tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardMarkup(
    tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardRow(
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY11", "KEY11"),
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY22", "KEY22"),
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("KEY33", "KEY33"),
    ),
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("token_bot") //Бот 

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60

    updates, err := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    for update := range updates {

        if update.Message == nil { // ignore non-Message updates
            continue
        }

        if update.CallbackQuery.Data == "KEY1" {
            fmt.Println("Нажата клавиша, = ", "KEY1", " !")
            //fmt.Println("TelegramID = ", Telegramid, "id =", Namefon[8], "Hash = ", Namefon[9], "tarif =", Namefon[11])
        }

        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)

        switch update.Message.Text {
        case "open":
            msg.ReplyMarkup = numericKeyboard
        case "close":
            msg.ReplyMarkup = tgbotapi.NewRemoveKeyboard(true)
            msg.ReplyMarkup = numericKeyboard2

        }

        if _, err := bot.Send(msg); err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if update.CallbackQuery != nil {
    updateCallbackQueryHandler(update.CallbackQuery)
    continue
}
if update.Message == nil {
    continue
}
```

update.Message опусти ниже update.CallbackQuery